# Shell script "git diff origin/master --name-only" throwing error fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree

Tags: git, bitbucket-pipelines

`git diff origin/master --name-only`

command in my bitbucket pipelines throwing below error. but works good in my local git bash.

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I am expectign it to return the files that are changed as of from master brnach. with --name-only it is returning only names of the changes files in my local git bash, but throwing above error in bitbuckt pipelines.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried what the error message suggested? `git diff --name-only origin/master --` If not, please do so. What is the outcome? Please add all the clarifications to your question by editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: the error message mentions `'master'`, not `'origin/master'`. Check the script for your bitbucket pipeline: do you check for `master` or `origin/master` ?

---

Second: depending on the options you set, your pipeline may well *not* have `origin/master` at all -- this may happen if you instruct your pipeline to only use a shallow clone.

- To check whether this is the case:

have your pipeline run `git branch -r` at some point, you will have the list of remote branches in the pipeline log. Also check how the refspec is set for `origin`:

```
git config --get-all remote.orgin.fetch
```

- To fix it:

run `git fetch origin master` in your pipeline.

If there is no refspec instructing how to fetch branches from origin, you may need to instead run:

```
git fetch origin +master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response @LeGEC. I have tried the below command and it worked, seems like bitbucket pipelines won't be having hierarchy like `origin/*` like our local. In the local Windows11 machine with VSCode I haven't observed any of these issues but on the bitbucket pipeline, it showed it popped out.

```bash
$ git diff --name-only master -- VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the default depth of history downloaded by de bitbucket pipelines runner was 50. If the tag or commit suplied in the diff was older, the error was rised. The solution was to specify a larger depth Example:

```
  - step:
      clone:   
        depth: 200
```